# z-index not working on modal created in react and modal not appearing on top

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, modal-dialog, react-modal

I have created on modal using HTMl and CSS in react but, modal is not working as expected when deployed on environment as I have set z-index of modal to be higher

But there are other component on page who has also z-index and as those component appears before modal component in html page order.

Model doesn't appear on top as expected.

IS there any way in react, so that we can override all existing z-index and modal will work as expected.
I am providing CSS code for modal overlay and modal

```
.modal-overlay{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    z-index: 5;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    overflow: scroll;
}
.modal{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-basis: auto;
    background-color: #fff;
    max-width: 375px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

Comment: Their markup order doesn't matter if the `z-index` is higher, so try with `z-index: 50000;`

Comment: I always put modals directly into the body - that way you  can give it a high z-index and you'll always know it will be in the top stacking context - especially as it is position fixed.  As it is a modal and will be hidden, it doesn't really matter where in your code you put it

Comment: @Pete , there are many component on page and some of the component has z-index set and when modal appears , part of it gets hidden by those component, no matter how big z-index i provide to this modal, it will not have any impact, only way it will appear on front is to remove the z-index of other component , which seems to be tough, it's something related to stacking context, but i am not able to resolve it

Comment: You need to show this in a [mcve] - I think you need to rethink your modal if you need parts from what triggers the modal to be on top of the modal - a modal is usually something that covers the whole screen - seems a bit stupid to have bits covering the screen and bits poking through

Comment: As @Pete suggest (both comments), if you use _modal_ stuff nested you can get into problems, so try to avoid that

Answer (score 1):

This method uses React Portal. U should have element with id="modal-root" in ur index html file. Every time u call a modal, the modal will come inside modal-root, Hence there will be no problem of z-index as u r rendering the Modal at the topmost **div**

Create a file Modal.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const modalRoot = document.getElementById('modal-root');

class Modal extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.el = document.createElement('div');
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    modalRoot.appendChild(this.el);
    console.log('Modal did mount');
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log('Modal will unmount');
    modalRoot.removeChild(this.el);
  }
  render() {
    return ReactDOM.createPortal(
      this.props.children,
      this.el,
    );
  }
}

export default Modal;
```

Create actual modal code

```
import React from 'react';

const ImageContainer = props => (
  <div className="modal d-block full-screen-popup" tabIndex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div className="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div className="modal-content">
        <div className="modal-header">
          <h6 className="modal-title text-center bold">Title</h6>
          <button type="button" className="close" onClick={props.onClose}>
            <span className="icon-close" />
          </button>
        </div>
        <div className="modal-body p-0">
          <div className="imageBody text-center">
            <img className="img-fluid" src={props.imgSrc} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);

export default ImageContainer;
```

Its CSS should be

```
.full-screen-popup {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.62);
}

.d-block {
    display: block!important;
}
.modal {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1050;
    display: none;
    outline: 0;
}
```

Then in any js file, Import the Modal, and pass the actual modal component.

```
renderImageModal = () => {
    if (this.state.showImageModal) {
      return (
        <Modal>
          <ImageContainer onClose={this.handleImageModalClose} imgSrc={this.state.link} />
        </Modal>);
    }
    return null;
  }

 handleModalOpenClick = () => {

    this.setState({
      showImageModal: true,
    });
  }

handleImageModalClose = () => {
    this.setState({
      showImageModal: false,

    });
  }


    render(){ 
     return(
       <button onclick={this.handleModalOpenClick}>Open Modal</button>
        {this.renderImageModal()})
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

The best way to create modal using `ReactJS` is to use `Portals`.

You can check the docs for portals [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) in the ReactJS docs or [here](https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/jGBWpE) the particular `Modal` example on codepen.